# Xamarin failed to codesign, resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I recently moved this Xamarin Forms app to a new developer account. It's been a few years since I've worked on it and I have not been able to get it to build. I recreated the provisioning profiles and signing certificates and made sure they are in the Keychain and set correctly for the iOS Build Settings in Visual Stuido Mac. All the packages are updated. I'm getting this codesign error.
[image: codesign exed with code 1 DACircularProgress.frameworki, et..]

This one mentions DACircularProgress.framework but I also get errors for several other frameworks and the iOS.app file itself.

In searching for solutions, I saw the issues with attributes on .png and various other files and ran all those xattr commands in the terminal to no avail.

I think it has something to do with moving it to a new developer account, or maybe moving Visual Studio to a new Macbook, but I have no idea where to start troubleshooting since all my searches for similar errors only come up with the file attributes problem from back in 2018.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please don't post code or errors as images

Comment: Sorry, here you go: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(3,3): Error: /usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1:
/Users/joshbula/Documents/Xamarin/FMEAMobile4/FMEAMobile4/FMEAMobile4.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/FMEAMobile4.iOS.app/Frameworks/SDWebImage.framework: replacing existing signature
/Users/joshbula/Documents/Xamarin/FMEAMobile4/FMEAMobile4/FMEAMobile4.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/FMEAMobile4.iOS.app/Frameworks/SDWebImage.framework: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed (FMEAMobile4.iOS)

Comment: please [edit] your question to include additional information

Answer (score 0):

These error messages mention old versions of frameworks that are no longer compatible with the latest versions of iOS and XCode due to the "Finder information, or similar detritus" no longer being allowed. To find which NuGet package uses these frameworks as dependencies, open (project directory)/obj/project.assets.json after a build attempt. In this case, it was the Stormlion.PhotoBrowser.Forms package, which hasn't been updated in over 5 years, so I removed that package and removed all the code that used it. I also had to delete all the /bin and /obj folders in the project and restart Visual Studio. After that, the project was built successfully.